# How to sort column with specific data separated by /

Tags: excel

I am trying to sort column with data like this:

input:

```
11/2
11/3a
11/2b
3/1
2/5
2/8
3/5
```

how should it be sorted:

```
2/5
2/8
3/1
3/5
11/2
11/2b
11/3b
```

the cell is always in format number1/number2[optional letter]

and should be sorted by number 1, then by number2, then by letter. How can I do this?

Comment: Use a helper column, or VBA.

Comment: You can also use `Power Query` available since Excel 2010

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1 - Excel**

Create two helper columns (Column B & Column C)

Column B Formula: `=LEFT(A1,FIND("/",A1)-1)`

Column C Formula: `=MID(A1,(FIND("/",A1)+1),(LEN(A1)-(FIND("/",A1))))`

Select all three columns and follow the below part to custom sort

Home - Editing - Sort & Filter - Custom Sort - Add Level

**Sort:**

[image]

**Method 2 - VBA**

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastRowA As Long, i As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRowA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To LastRowA

            .Range("B" & i).Value = Split(.Range("A" & i).Value, "/")(0)
            .Range("C" & i).Value = Split(.Range("A" & i).Value, "/")(1)

        Next i

        .Sort.SortFields.Clear
        .Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("B1:B" & LastRowA), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("C1:C" & LastRowA), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

        With .Sort
            .SetRange Range("A1:C" & LastRowA)
            .Header = xlGuess
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With

    End With

End Sub
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: If you are going to use build in options (which is absolutely fine), I would use text to columns instead of formulas. Upvoted, but I'd say you have given OP an answer for very minimal effort from his end.

Comment: i have also add VBA code, which in my opinion is better

Comment: FWIW, If you choose to go VBA you don't need to loop.

Comment: Any ides on how to spit the values in order to avoid loop?

Comment: Sure `Dim rng as range` and then `Set rng = .Range("A1:A" & LastRowA)` and then `rng.TextToColumns Destination:=.Range("B1"), Other:=True, OtherChar:="/"`